# Ótica ou Óptica?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

Estou confuso. Uso a variante europeia da Língua e adotei há muito o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990.

Como deverei grafar, com referência aos diversos temas (ciência, questões mundanas, espaço comercial), **óptica** ou **ótica**?

- "Na minha ótica..."
- Espaço onde se compram óculos
- Ramo da Física

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estes ambos links estiverem corretos:

- http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/optica-optico-otica-ou-otico/
- http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-otica-e-optica.html

Ambas palavras são sinônimos, todavia a palavra ótica/ótico é usado preferencialmente quando falado, acredito que tanto no português europeu, quanto português brasileiro.

O que diferencia são as suas origens antes do Português.

- Óptico(a) provavelmente tem origem na palavra *optikós* (**com** P):

  Se refere a uma parte da física que estuda a luz e dos fenômenos da visão. Pode também se referir ao estabelecimento específico para fabricação e venda de óculos e outros instrumentos ópticos. Figurativamente, esta palavra é usada para designar o aspecto de objetos vistos à distância, ou seja, perspectiva e ainda uma forma de ver a realidade, ou seja, um ponto de vista.

  Sendo um adjetivo, indica uma qualidade relativa à óptica ou à visão. Sendo um substantivo masculino, se refere ao fabricante de instrumentos ópticos ou a um perito da óptica.
- Ótico(a) provavelmente tem origem na palavra *otikós* (**sem** P):

  É um adjetivo e se refere ao ouvido ou à região auditiva. Significa ainda o medicamento usado em doenças nos ouvidos. Ótica aparece, neste sentido, como sendo o feminino de ótico.

  Daí a `otite` é a inflamação do ouvido, a `otalgia` é a popular dor de ouvido, o `otologista` é o médico especializado em doenças do ouvido e `otorrino` é abreviação de `otorrinolaringologista`, que é o especialista em ouvido, nariz e laringe.

Para concluir:

1. No português ambas tem o mesmo sentido
2. Segundo o Novo Acordo Ortográfico, que entrou em vigor em janeiro de 2009, as consoantes `c` e `p` que não se *leem* nas palavras deverão ser abolidas.
3. Ambas apenas tem origens diferentes

Comment: O segundo link aí indica que "a palavra óptica só pode ser usada para os fenômenos da visão e ótica pode ser sinônimo de óptica ou relativo ao ouvido." Portanto, é muito relativo dizer que ambas têm o mesmo sentido. E também acho peculiar que o "p" não tenha sido abolido em "óptica", ao contrário do que indicas na conclusão.

Comment: @E_net4 disse que deve ser abolida e não que foi abolida, se entendi isto não foi algo "definitivo". Todavia irei revisar a resposta ;)

Comment: Aqui no Brasil eu acho (repito, acho) que até o século XIX usava-se "óptica" e o "p" simplesmente caiu.  Caso eu esteja certo,  as duas palavras não podem ter origens distintas.

Answer (score 1):

Vocabulário Ortográfico Português ao ataque!

O substantivo feminino [ótica](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=121639) tem como variante AO *óptica* apenas no português do Brasil.

Reciprocamente, [óptica](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=4327) consta como sendo uma palavra brasileira, com variante *ótica*.

Resumindo, é aceitável escrever *ótica* tanto no português de Portugal como no Brasil, e *óptica* apenas no português do Brasil. A grafia PT-PT foi alterada no AO1990 porque os portugueses não pronunciam a letra *p* em "óptica".

Comment: Um momento!  Brasileiros não escrevem e nem pronunciam o "p" em "óptica".   Talvez em 1916 o fizessem, mas não em 2016.

Comment: De certeza? Para o substantivo?

Comment: Sim, certeza absoluta.

Comment: Sou brasileiro, nunca escrevi com "p" e nem a pronuncia que aprendi era com "p", sempre foi ótica.

Comment: Seja, vou tratar de editar quando tiver tempo. Mas entretanto, há que entender porque é que temos a grafia "óptica" aqui indicada. Poderá ser um caso de pronúncia variável no Brasil?

Comment: No google você acha aproximadamente 27.900.000 resultados para óptica que segundo @Centaurus o brasileiro não usa. Em todo caso, atualmente as lojas adotaram o nome Ótica, em sua maioria; e se usa bastante óptica para a ciência, ou visão pessoal sobre assuntos, mas ninguém fala esse P.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Vou mais longe, nem na faculdade de medicina, mais especificamente na cadeira de Oftalmologia, eu jamais ouvi algum professor pronunciar o "p" de ótica.  Eu não pronuncio e, em 42 anos de profissão jamais ouvi um colega pronunciar o "p".

Comment: @AndréLyra  No Google, se a tua pesquisa for direcionada para "país - Brasil", "língua - português",  o resultado é o seguinte: ótica =  4.000.000 resultados, óptica  800.00 resultados.  Os 27.900.000 que tu encontraste referem-se ao mundo inteiro, incluindo todas as línguas neo-latinas.

Comment: Apenas para ficar claro: significa que nas três situações por mim acima descritas, posso usar `ótica` ?